# Within the interval {0,1} we randomly choose two numbers: x and y and Determine the probability that the number 5x+y is divisible by 3

Tags: probability, self-study

my approach was like this ,

Assuming  ∈ ℕ∗,two numbers are drawn randomly. Lets call the first one    and the second  . Furthermore we learn that both are drawn from the uniform distribution on  {0,1}. (Actually the distribution is not given, but I chose a simple one to not complicate matters). Because the two events are supposed to be independent (which I also assume),
we can draw all possibly combinations as a pair of numbers  (,)  that is (0,1) & (1,0),

We need to establish the probability  the number 5x+y  is divisible by 3.

case1:
when  (,)  = (0,1) :
we get 5x+y = 1

1 is not divisible by 3.

case2:
when  (,)  = (1,0) :
we get 5x+y = 5

5 is not divisible by 3.

so the probability that  5x+y within interval {0,1} is divisible by 3 is zero.

I am definitely not convinced by my approach . kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you're missing half the cases. Since $x$ and $y$ are independent, they can take the same value; we're sampling with replacement, if you like. As well as $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, $(x,y)$ can also be equal to $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$. Add those two cases, and you should get the answer you're looking for.